# How can I determine what caused a dconf key to change values?

Tags: dconf

I'm having an issue where a dconf key is changing for some reason, and I'd like to know what is causing it to change. I know that I can use `dconf watch` to watch for when the value changes, but I'm hoping I can find a way to determine what sent the request for the value to be changed in the first place.

Comment: Check if there is something on DBus, use dbus-monitor CLI or d-feet GUI